Adding custom validate tag in OpenAPI description
I'm trying to understand how does the OpenAPI Specification work using go language.
I created yaml file which I want to generate to my go code for requests and responses structs.
But some structs need the custom validator. So wrote it in this way:
var validate *validator.Validate

func init() {
  validate = validator.New()
  if err := validate.RegisterValidation("email", validateEmail); err != nil {
    logger.Fatalf("Couldn't register email validator, err=%v", err)
  }
}

func validateEmail(fl validator.FieldLevel) bool {
  email := fl.Field().String()

  emailRegex := `^[a-zA-Z0-9._%+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,}$`

  return regexp.MustCompile(emailRegex).MatchString(email)
}

And not I can write struct with such validator tag
type somStruct struct {
  Email string `validate:"email"`
}

Is it possible to add to an OpenAPI description that will be generated to such struct?

how are you generating the open api? you can specify this as the pattern json schema configuration

I'm generating it using this command openapi-generator-cli generate -i ./openapi.yaml -g go -o ./test --skip-validate-spec
But isn't pattern field a field for regexp? But if I want to create validator that will have bigger functional?

did you try adding the format keyword?  I think openapi-generator-cli uses the format annotations
components:
  schemas:
   User:
    type: object
    properties:
      email:
        type: string
        format: email

